# Keycloak "Invalid parameter: redirect_uri"

Tags: keycloak

After configuring a client named 'steeringclientui' in keycloak as in the picture below

[image]

when I am trying to access http://localhost:8080/realms/steeringappdev/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=steeringclientui&response_type=code&scope=openid&redirect_url=http://localhost:8080/sample&state=asdasdas

I've got

[image]

I can access without any problem http://localhost:8080/realms/steeringappdev/.well-known/openid-configuration and the response is :

[image]

If more info is needed, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#AuthRequest

You need parameter `redirect_uri` (not `redirect_url`) + value should be URL encoded. So correct Authentication Request URL should be:

```
http://localhost:8080/realms/steeringappdev/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=steeringclientui&response_type=code&scope=openid&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fsample&state=asdasdas
```